# Custom channel content based on user

Tags: members, channel

I am looking for a little guidance with a new ExpressionEngine project. I have a channel called adventures that contains a group of channel fields. I also have members that can signup and login to the website and eventually purchase these adventures (Which will be done with a plugin). I am looking for a way to allow a user to customize some of the channel fields inside an adventure and then display it only to that user. Each user would be able to create and customize their own adventure based on the generic version I have created.

The user to be able to customize these within a website form interface.

Any guidance would be helpful and if I need to explore PHP over ExpressionEngine code to execute user specific channel field content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Safecracker to allow a member to create / update / delete entries from your channels on the front end of your site. [Guide is here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html), and a [few examples here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/examples.html). I don't know how much interaction you would need between the plugin you mentioned and safecracker, but I would do some really basic tests to get the feel of it.